# connected points and smallest value

Tags: matlab

I would like to know how I can to take each `D(Points)` and look at its connexed points (in 8 connex) but only on the side of the limit (ie the diagonal points top and bottom right and on the same line to the right, ie 3 points Connect on 8) and select the coordinates of the connexed point which has the smallest value of D. And I would like to repeat this until I obtain that the smallest value of D equal 0

```
    % Creation of matrix example
    c=zeros(500,500);
    c(1:100,250)=1;c(100:300,200)=1;c(300:400,270)=1;  c(400:500,250)=1;
    c(100,200:250)=1;c(300,200:270)=1;c(400,250:270)=1;

     figure, imagesc(c)


    Points= [211,388;64,200;160,437;237,478;110,270;100,34];
    hold on, plot(Points(:,1),Points(:,2),'ro'), hold off

    %Distance map
    D = bwdist(cumsum(c, 2) > 0, 'euclidean');
    figure, imagesc(D)
```

Answer (score 1):

The key function here is `sub2ind` which converts subscripts to linear indices. It is very handy when you need to work on specific points inside an array.

```
% Let's prepare the 8 shifts needed (i add a no-move shift in first place to simplify the algorithm)

delta_x = [0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
delta_y = [0, -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1];

sz_D = size(D);
n_points = size(Points, 1);
is_running = true;

while is_running
    % All the shift combinaisons
    new_ind_x = bsxfun(@plus, Points(:,1), delta_x);
    new_ind_y = bsxfun(@plus, Points(:,2), delta_y);

    % Saturation to stay in the image
    new_ind_x = min(max(new_ind_x, 1), sz_D(2));
    new_ind_y = min(max(new_ind_y, 1), sz_D(1));

    % Get the values in D and find the index of the minimum points
    points_lin_ind = sub2ind(sz_D, new_ind_y, new_ind_x);
    points_val = D(points_lin_ind);
    [min_values, min_ind] = min(points_val, [], 2);

    % Select subscripts in new_ind_x and new_ind_y
    min_lin_ind = sub2ind([n_points, 9], (1:n_points).', min_ind);
    Points = [new_ind_x(min_lin_ind), new_ind_y(min_lin_ind)];

    % Exit condition
    if all(min_values == 0)
        is_running = false;
    end
end
```

PS : Not tested.